# NSMakeRect tracking slider Swift 3

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to get a `rectangle` to track with a slider thumb (not replace the thumb)

To achieve this I'm using a custom class called `gatebox` with a `NSMakeRect (80,(sliderValue),80,40)`.

I have used a global variable just for the ease of reading but have tried calling the function from the main controller and the results are still the same. So I thought it easier to use a global.

I have also tried putting the fader on the custom view.
The rectangle does indeed track with the slider but only the part that is contained with in the thumb width as per this picture.

[image]

Here is my code its a bit rough and ready but shows the problem
thanks for reading if you got this far.

Here is the AppDelegate:

```
//  AppDelegate.swift
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

var mainWindowController: MainWindowController?

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    let mainWindowController = MainWindowController(windowNibName: "MainWindowController")
    mainWindowController.showWindow(self)
    self.mainWindowController = mainWindowController
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}}
```

Here is the mainController:

```
    //  MainWindowController.swift

var globalVariable = 10.00

import Cocoa

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {
    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func slider001(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let data = sender.doubleValue!
        globalVariable = data
        print("data", data)
    }
}//end of the world
```

Here is the custom class for custom view:

```
    //  GateBox.swift

import Cocoa

class gateBoxView: NSView {
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        Swift.print("did you fire")

        self.needsDisplay = true //New addition

        let mybackgroundColor = NSColor.init(colorLiteralRed: 0.9, green: 0.4, blue: 0.4, alpha: 0.2)
        mybackgroundColor.set()
        NSBezierPath.fill(bounds)

        //just using global variable for testing
        let myY = globalVariable * 0.85
        Swift.print("myY",myY)

        //Draw rectangle and track slider
        let myRectangleColor = NSColor(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
        let myRectangle = NSMakeRect(75.0, CGFloat(myY),40.0 , 20.0)
        let cPath: NSBezierPath = NSBezierPath(rect: myRectangle)
        myRectangleColor.set()
        cPath.fill()

    }//eo overide
```

Comment: You're not calling super.draw(rect)? This might be messing with the cleaning up of the drawing after each frame. Try putting it at the start of the drawing function

Comment: my apologises but i'm unsure where to add super. I tried various places could you elaborate.

Comment: Just above `Swift.print("did you fire")`. It's worth noting that you don't need the Swift part of that too, `print("did you fire")` works fine too.

Comment: i'm very sorry but  override func super.draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) gives an error  Keyword 'super' cannot be used as an identifier here

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add

```
self.needsDisplay = true
```

to the  GateBox.swift file as amended